# Remove gap between 3 different div class

Tags: html, css

Hello I just Confused anybody helps me 
i was trying to remove these gaps between text but not done
please check the code and give the working code 
with CSS.
Please help me to remove gaps and Bring it in the middle.

```css
#DIV_1 {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  bottom: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 212.938px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -30px;
  width: 270.391px;
  perspective-origin: 86.6875px 106.469px;
  transform-origin: 86.6875px 106.469px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://psdstar.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hd-3d-free-Lotus-Flower-275x155.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_1:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
}


/*#DIV_1:after*/

#DIV_1:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
}


/*#DIV_1:before*/

#H3_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 260.391px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 86.6875px 65px;
  transform-origin: 86.6875px 65px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 32px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 68px 0px 25px;
}


/*#H3_2*/

#H3_2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 32px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H3_2:after*/

#H3_2:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 32px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H3_2:before*/

#H4_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 260.391px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 86.6875px 10px;
  transform-origin: 86.6875px 10px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 17px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: px 0px 18px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H4_3*/

#H4_3:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 17px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H4_3:after*/

#H4_3:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 17px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H4_3:before*/

#A_4 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  top: 0px;
  width: 104.031px;
  z-index: 10;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 52.0156px 15px;
  transform-origin: 52.0156px 15px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to left, rgb(134, 201, 168), rgb(161, 201, 103)) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 20px / 30px Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0px 75.6875px 0px 75.6719px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}


/*#A_4*/

#A_4:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 20px / 30px Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#A_4:after*/

#A_4:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 20px / 30px Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#A_4:before*/

#DIV_1 {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  bottom: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 212.938px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -30px;
  width: 270.391px;
  perspective-origin: 86.6875px 106.469px;
  transform-origin: 86.6875px 106.469px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://psdstar.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hd-3d-free-Lotus-Flower-275x155.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_1:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
}


/*#DIV_1:after*/

#DIV_1:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
}


/*#DIV_1:before*/

#H3_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 260.391px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 86.6875px 65px;
  transform-origin: 86.6875px 65px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 32px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  padding: 68px 0px 25px;
}


/*#H3_2*/

#H3_2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 32px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H3_2:after*/

#H3_2:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 32px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H3_2:before*/

#H4_3 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 260.391px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 86.6875px 10px;
  transform-origin: 86.6875px 10px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 17px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: px 0px 18px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H4_3*/

#H4_3:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 17px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H4_3:after*/

#H4_3:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 17px / normal Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#H4_3:before*/

#A_4 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  top: 0px;
  width: 104.031px;
  z-index: 10;
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  perspective-origin: 52.0156px 15px;
  transform-origin: 52.0156px 15px;
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to left, rgb(134, 201, 168), rgb(161, 201, 103)) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 20px / 30px Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0px 75.6875px 0px 75.6719px;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}


/*#A_4*/

#A_4:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 20px / 30px Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#A_4:after*/

#A_4:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 20px / 30px Arial, Abel-Regular, Helvetica;
  list-style: none outside none;
  outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
}


/*#A_4:before*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <h3 id="H3_2">
    2000
  </h3>
  <h4 id="H4_3">
    Free Templates
  </h4> <a href="https://psdstar.com/new-wallpapers/" rel="nofollow" id="A_4">More</a>
```

[image: ERROR Screenshot]

I was not able to add long CSS code here so please check this urlv

[Origin Error Link jsfiddle.net editor](https://jsfiddle.net/memmu2wb/60/)

Comment: which spacing you want to remove??/

Comment: I want to keep it center and remove margin  on 3 texts I don't find it out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your text to the middle of the div, remove all the padding/margin you've set on it.
Then add flexbox to your parent div:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: Hello, I am not able to figure it out and trying to removing the margin but not solved. also added your code. Can u try in your end, please? I won't keep it to center all text and reduce gaps margin all from all text.